# Return a resultset as JSON text—using pretty formatting

Tags: oracle, json, oracle-21c

In Oracle 21c, it looks like we can return a resultset as JSON text:

```
SELECT json_object(*)
from dual;

result:
{"DUMMY":"X"}
```

That works in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9abea6f8f6c5d470bb33335acdd9e413):

[image]

**Question:**

Is there a way to return the JSON text using pretty formatting?

```
{
   "DUMMY":"X"
}
```

Related: [Select JSON text of SDO_GEOMETRY using SQL](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4498005/select-json-text-of-sdo-geometry-using-sql#latest)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[As documented](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions091.htm#CJAGDHAA), you can add `PRETTY` to a JSON function to prettify it

```
SELECT json_object(* PRETTY)
from dual;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=ec9d923a4026f5a8efcc121b8cdd3415)

**Output**

```
{
  "DUMMY" : "X"
}
```